# OpenCVにて動画データ表示不可。

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

現在AnacondaにてOpenCVの学習をしております。しかし、動画データをSpyder上で表示しようとしたところ、エラーは何も返ってきてないのにもかかわらず、指定動画が再生表示されません。

使用環境: Anaconda3(Python 2.7.13), Windows 7, OpenCV 3.2.0

試みた内容は下記です。

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Traffic.mpg')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

ご助言のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCVの`VideoCapture`は、デフォルトだとAVIファイルからの読み込みしかサポートしません。

FFmpegオプション有効でビルドされたOpenCVならば、対応フォーマットが増えた気がします（未確認）。AnacondaでインストールされるOpenCVライブラリのビルドオプションが不明ですが、おそらく自前でソースコードからビルドが必要でしょう。

Comment: AVIに変換したところ表示に成功いたしました。ご助言ありがとうございました。